# Clustered (grouped) standard errors MLE in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, clustered-standard-errors, sandwich

I'm doing the following maximum likelihood estimation using mle2 function from *[bbmle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/index.html)* package:

```
library(bbmle)
llik.probit2<- function(aL,beta, Ks, Kw, Bs, Bw, dta){
  Y <- as.matrix(dta$qualified)
  sce1 <- as.matrix(dta$eds)
  wce1 <- as.matrix(dta$edw)
  sce1_obs <- (as.matrix(dta$eds_obs))
  wce1_obs <- (as.matrix(dta$edw_obs))
  obs <- as.matrix(dta$CombinedObservable1)
  c <- as.matrix(dta$const)
  phi <- pnorm(ifelse(Y == 0, -1, 1) * (-aL*c + beta*obs + (Bs+Bs*Ks-aL)*sce1 -beta*Ks*sce1_obs + (Bw+Bw*Kw-aL)*wce1 - beta*Kw*wce1_obs), log.p = TRUE)
  -sum(phi)
}

starting.pointmle2 <- list(aL=1.4, beta=0.3, Ks=0.5, Kw=0.5, Bs=0.5, Bw=0.5)

result1 <- mle2(llik.probit2, start = starting.pointmle2, data=list(dta=Mydata), skip.hessian=FALSE)
```

I need to estimate clustered standard  errors of this model, clustering on variable *c_id*.  I'm trying to implement the *sandwich* estimator but cannot retrieve 'meat' part from mle2 output. I have also tried with *nlm*, and *optim* (mle2 is basically wrapper for these methods)
Any advice how to do it? In general is there any package which provides functions to calculate clustered standard errors for MLE estimation of a general function?

Here is is a small sample of the data file (MyData) in csv format:

```
const,qualified,eds,edw,eds_obs,edw_obs,CombinedObservable1,c_id
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.6838316166,1
1,1,0,1,0,0,-0.1433684328,1
1,0,0,1,0,0.0758113685,0.0758113685,1
1,0,1,0,0.2084778637,0,0.2084778637,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.1622519262,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.5061082675,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.6952748613,34
1,0,1,0,0.9883178986,0,0.9883178986,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.5311805315,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,2.7546881325,34
1,1,1,0,-0.2174263974,0,-0.2174263974,34
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.4397037288,1
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.3189328097,1
1,0,0,1,0,0,-0.6132276964,12
1,0,0,1,0,0,0.2459941348,12
1,0,0,1,0,0.0589196966,0.0589196966,12
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how can we apply two-way clustering using with Robcov function?

Comment: I faced a similar problem to which Achim Zeiles offered a solution that works for me:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451853/how-to-cluster-standard-errors-when-fitting-a-model-using-maximum-likelihood-est

Answer (score 2):

With out sample data it's hard to test what you are looking for given your code, but I would suggest using the [`rms`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf) package.  It is a great package and has what you are looking for.

In particular,

> `lrm` : Fit binary and proportional odds ordinal logistic regression
>   models using maximum likelihood estimation or penalized maximum
>   likelihood estimation
>
> `robcov`: Uses the Huber-White method to adjust the variance-covariance
>   matrix of a fit from maximum likelihood or least squares, to correct
>   for heteroscedasticity and for correlated responses from cluster
>   samples

Here is an example using your data provided with a *very* simple model:

**Sample data**

```
df <- structure(list(const = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), qualified = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), eds = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), edw = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    eds_obs = c(0, 0, 0, 0.2084778637, 0, 0, 0, 0.9883178986, 
    0, 0, -0.2174263974, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), edw_obs = c(0, 0, 0.0758113685, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0589196966), CombinedObservable1 = c(-0.6838316166, 
    -0.1433684328, 0.0758113685, 0.2084778637, -0.1622519262, 
    -0.5061082675, -0.6952748613, 0.9883178986, -0.5311805315, 
    2.7546881325, -0.2174263974, -0.4397037288, -0.3189328097, 
    -0.6132276964, 0.2459941348, 0.0589196966), c_id = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L)), .Names = c("const", "qualified", "eds", "edw", 
"eds_obs", "edw_obs", "CombinedObservable1", "c_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

**Regression w/o clustering:**

```
library(rms)
d <- datadist(df)
options("datadist" = "d")
mod <- lrm(qualified ~ eds, data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = qualified ~ eds, data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
                     Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                        Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs            16    LR chi2      1.19    R2       0.135    C       0.679    
 0             14    d.f.            1    g        0.582    Dxy     0.357    
 1              2    Pr(> chi2) 0.2760    gr       1.790    gamma   0.714    
max |deriv| 1e-09                         gp       0.083    tau-a   0.083    
                                          Brier    0.099                     

          Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept -2.4849 1.0408 -2.39  0.0170  
eds        1.7918 1.6073  1.11  0.2649
```

**Cluster around c_id:**

```
robcov(mod, df$c_id, method = c('huber'))

Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = qualified ~ eds, data = df, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs             16    LR chi2      1.19    R2       0.135    C       0.679    
 0              14    d.f.            1    g        0.582    Dxy     0.357    
 1               2    Pr(> chi2) 0.2760    gr       1.790    gamma   0.714    
Cluster on df$c_id                         gp       0.083    tau-a   0.083    
Clusters         3                         Brier    0.099                     
max |deriv|  1e-09                                                            

          Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept -2.4849 0.8250 -3.01  0.0026  
eds        1.7918 0.8250  2.17  0.0299
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I have also included a small data sample (csv)

Comment: @Nidjsi I've updated the answer to provide a simple model with the package.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Amstell. Unfortunately, I think this solution is not suitable for the problem I have. If you look at my specification of log-likelihood function, I'm actually estimating the parameters of the following probit model.  
$Prob(Y=1|sce1, wce1, sce1\_obs, wce1\_obs, obs)= \Phi(-aL + \beta *obs + (Bs + Bs* Ks -aL)*sce1 -\beta *Ks*sce1\_obs+(Bw+Bw *Kw-aL)*wce1 - \beta *Kw *wce1\_obs)$
and I'm interested in parameters $a_L, \beta, Bs, Ks, Bw, Kw$.

Comment: [Part 2]If I use one among many R's function to estimate probit (i.e. **glm**) I don't get the estimates of my parameters of interest, but I get the estimates $(\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5)$ of corresponding parameters of a different model
 $Prob(Y=1|sce1, wce1, sce1\_obs, wce1\_obs, obs)= \Phi(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 *obs + \alpha_2*sce1 -\alpha_3*sce1\_obs+\alpha_4*wce1 - \alpha_5wce1\_obs )$. This is because in the case of solution you have proposed I cannot write the expression *formula* in function **lrm** appropriately.

Comment: [Part 3] Given that I'm not interested in $\alpha$'s but in other parameters, I esitmate the model by maximizing log-likelihood function, rather than using **glm** or **lrm** function.
However I don't know how to use the output from that procedure to solve my problem (for example by using **robcov** function as you do in your solution)

Comment: @Nidjsi Your responses to my answer should be added to the question. One problem is that you are after a specification that can not be reproduced from your example above, so I simple provided a baseline example using the `rms` package.  If your question does not provide a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) then no one will be able to test your specification and provide you with an answer.